# Extending Ubuntu home partition using Gparted in dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, partitioning, gparted

I am using a dual boot system with Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10. When I set up Ubuntu, I used only 100 GB for it. Now I want to add another 50 GB to it using Gparted. I have already created an ullocated space of 50 GB and I want to add this to my /home partition. But The unallocated 50 GB and /home are not contiguous. How shall I do it then?

Here is an attached Gparted image for reference.
[image: Gparted photo]

In this image, as you can see the /root partition is /dev/sda9 and the /home partition is /dev/sda11. I want to assign the unallocated 50 GB space to /home. How should i do that?

Comment: I can help you do this... question though... it looks like /dev/sda11 has plenty of free space right now... please explain. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema I am going to add data after I increase the size

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Comment: @heynnema please refer to the reply to your answer for status..thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or lose data.

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a **swapoff** on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a **swapon** on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower pane of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- start `gparted`
- **move** /dev/sda9 partition all the way left

  - **note**: if you wish to **resize** /dev/sda9, now is the time to do it
- did you remember to **swapoff** /dev/sda10?
- **move** /dev/sda10 partition all the way left
- **move** /dev/sda11 partition all the way left
- **resize** the right side of /dev/sda11 all the way right
- click the Apply icon

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked like a charm. First I turned swap off and then used GParted for the whole process. Although, I do not think turning swap on/off had any effect because it had 0 space used. Still, I followed the given procedure.

Comment: @KakashiHatake You turn it off because even though there may be 0 space used, the partition is still open, and you couldn't have moved it.

Comment: But since I haven't booted into Ubuntu and opened GParted from a live USB, wouldn't the swap partition be automatically off?

Comment: @KakashiHatake No